# How to access a sub element of a custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, custom-element

I have this custom element. (Tell me if there is something wrong with this construction as I am new to custom elements)

```
class Navbar extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
            <nav id='navbar'>
                <i class="fas fa-home" id='home-i'></i>
                <hr class="line">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left" id='back-i'></i>
                <i class="fas fa-brain"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-lightbulb" id='quiz-i'></i>
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" id='exit-i'></i>
            </nav>
        `
    }
}
customElements.define('left-navbar', Navbar)
```

And I want to access one of the icons to add some button functionality, which involves calling `.querySelector`.

```
const homeBtn = document.querySelector('left-navbar').root.querySelector('#home-i');

homeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
    changePageTitle(0);
})
```

However, upon run time I get an error stating `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelector')`. Since `document.querySelector('left-navbar').root` is null. I am confused as to what I am supposed to put in as the parameter for the first `.querySelector`.

Also, here is the HTML part.

```
<body>
        <main>
            <!-- Heading -->
            <h1 id='reading-heading'>Chapter ###</h1>

            <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <left-navbar></left-navbar>
```

Comment: maybe `const homeBtn = document.querySelector('left-navbar #home-i');` ?

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. Maybe it has something to do with interacting with the shadow DOM?

Comment: Yep! Thanks for the amazing answer!